# Rearranging javascript object structure

Tags: javascript, json

I am looking at an object with the following structure:

```
[
  [
    {
      "attr1":"1",
      "attr2":"2",
      "attr3":"3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "attr1":"1",
      "attr2":"2",
      "attr3":"3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "attr1":"1",
      "attr2":"2",
      "attr3":"3"
    }
  ]
]
```

Just focusing on the structure of it, all I need to do with this object is to re-arrange it so that it ends up with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "attr1":"1",
    "attr2":"2",
    "attr3":"3"
  },
  {
    "attr1":"1",
    "attr2":"2",
    "attr3":"3"
  },
  {
    "attr1":"1",
    "attr2":"2",
    "attr3":"3"
  }
]
```

How can this be done in either pure Javascript or in core jQ library?

Comment: So you just want to take the first element of each inner array? You could get away with just `myArray.map(x=>x[0])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you just need to remove the second-level arrays. Easily done with **[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**.

```js
var old = [
  [
    {
      "attr1":"1",
      "attr2":"2",
      "attr3":"3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "attr1":"1",
      "attr2":"2",
      "attr3":"3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "attr1":"1",
      "attr2":"2",
      "attr3":"3"
    }
  ]
];

// Map loops through an array and returns a new array filled with whatever the 
// supplied callback function returns. 
var newArry = old.map(function(value){
  // Get the first object stored in the second-level array, but not the array itself
  return value[0];  
});

console.log(newArry);
```

Comment: you expect only one item in an array, it does not look very versatile.

Comment: @NinaScholz True, but the OP was specific when he said what the structure he was dealing was.

Answer (score 0):

`Array#reduce` may be helpful.

```js
var arr = [[{"attr1":"1","attr2":"2","attr3":"3"}],[{"attr1":"1","attr2":"2","attr3":"3"}],[{"attr1":"1","attr2":"2","attr3":"3"}]], 
    res = arr.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b));

    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var data = [[{ attr1: "1", attr2: "2", attr3: "3" }], [{ attr1: "1", attr2: "2", attr3: "3" }], [{ attr1: "1", attr2: "2", attr3: "3" }]],
    flat = [].concat(...data);

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
var data = [[{ attr1: "1", attr2: "2", attr3: "3" }], [{ attr1: "1", attr2: "2", attr3: "3" }], [{ attr1: "1", attr2: "2", attr3: "3" }]],
    flat = [].concat.apply([], data);

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus, the second should work for older javascript implementations.